# Create method to a slice type

Tags: go

I am new to golang. I am trying to add a method to a slice. The method is just a wrapper of append, which does not work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type SliceStr []string

func (ss *SliceStr) Add(s string) {
    ss = append(ss, s)
}

func main() {
    var s SliceStr

    s.Add("hello")
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

prog.go:10:12: first argument to append must be slice; have *SliceStr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting a pointer to `SliceStr` (`*SliceStr`), not `SliceStr` and therefore not a slice-type. Just dereference the pointer

```
func (ss *SliceStr) Add(s string) {
    *ss = append(*ss, s)
}
```

and it works just fine. `*ss = ...` sets the value `ss` is pointing to and the `*ss` in the call to [`append`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) passes it the value `ss` is pointing to, instead of the pointer.